# Why does my Google Analytics (GA4) purchase event show as a order coupon?

Tags: events, google-analytics, analytics, gtag.js

I'm working on updating some universal analytics code to GA4. I do not use the parameter name "coupon" anywhere in my code. However, when I check in analytics "Purchase revenue by order coupon" I'm getting the price of my normal purchase. Since this doesn't contain the word "coupon" anywhere I am at a loss to know why this is happening?

I've tried commenting out everything except purchases but it still happens with purchase. I use the gtag() events: "purchase", "begin_checkout", "view_item_list" and "view_item". Here is an example of my "purchase" event code:

```
gtag("event", "purchase", {
    currency: data.currency,
    value: data.orderTotal,
    transaction_id: '' + data.transactionId,
    tax: data.taxAmount,
    shipping: data.shippingAmount,
    affiliation: IR.global.websiteName,
    items: _.map(data.orderlines, function (p){
        return {
            item_name: p.productName,
            item_id: p.productId,
            item_code: p.productCode,
            item_brand: p.productBrand,
            price: data.tradeMode ? p.productPrice : p.unitPriceBeforeTax,
            quantity: p.productQuantity,
            weight: p.weight || 0,
        };
    })
});
```